# Mensagem indesejada ao exibir notificação na área de trabalho

Tags: c#, notificação, notifyicon

[image: Mensagem indesejada ao exibir notificação na área de trabalho]

Olá, estou exibindo uma notificação na área de trabalho, mas embaixo da mensagem aparece "vshost32.exe". Gostaria de saber como remover isso. Obg.

Meu código:

```
notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(10, "Lembrete ", " Você tem 10 contas a pagar ", ToolTipIcon.Info);
```

Comment: provavelmente você está em depuração no visual studio, e o sistema operacional mostra o nome do processo que está mostrando a mensagem. Depois de publicado o aplicativo, nesse lugar deve aparecer o nome do seu executável. Isso é o sistema operacional que mostra, você não tem como remover na aplicação.

Comment: Valeu amigo, muito obrigado.